# How to link two model in django and fetch data from them in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I create two model name subject and section if I create a model name maths I want to create some section in it which is one to one so I am trying to load the page of a section acc to the subject like I click on maths link only the section which is relate to math open no other section open I think you understand so here is my code
my models.py

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False,)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='subject thumbnail', blank = False)
    total_Section = models.FloatField(default='0')
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Section(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_section = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='section_vedios', blank=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    content_duration = models.DurationField(blank=False)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my views.py for subject

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    subject_list = Subject.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'home.html', {'subject_list': subject_list })
```

my views.py for sections

```
@login_required
def sections(request):
    return render (request, 'sections.html',)
```

my html for subject it worked

```
<ul>
      {% for subject in subject_list %}
     <li class="sub"> <a name='thumb' class="thumb" href="{% url 'subjects:section' %}"><img class="thumbnail"  src="{{ subject.thumbnail.url }}" alt=""> 
        <span><strong> {{ subject.name }} </strong> </span> </a>
        <p>No of Section : {{ subject.total_section }} </p> </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

my html for viewing section according to subject by clicking link it is not showing anything

```
<li class="sub"> <a name='thumb' class="thumb" href="#">
    <span><strong> {{ subject.section.title }} </strong> </span> </a>
    <p>Name: {{ subject.section.teacher }} </p> {{ subject.section.price }} </li>
    </div>
```

my urls.py for home html in which subject are rendering

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('', views.my_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('SectionWise/',views.home,name='home'),
    path('edit-profile/',views.edit_profile,name='edit')
]
```

my urls.py for section

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Section/', views.sections, name='section'),
    path('add_section/',views.add_sections,name='add_section')
]
```

I tried to use above method like for subject but in every link it shows all the section no matter which subject link you are clicking

adding as asked

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('section/<int:section_id>/', views.sections, name='section'),
    path('add_section/',views.add_sections,name='add_section')
]
```

my home.html

```
{% for subject in subject_list %}
      <a href="{% url 'subjects:section' subject.section.id %}">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="{{ subject.thumbnail.url }}" class="card-img-top"       alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{subject.id}} {{ subject.name }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{ subject.about }}</p>
          
          <hr>
          <p class="number" > No of Section:<strong> {{ subject.total_Section }}</strong></p>
          <p class="last"> Last update:<strong> {{ subject.update_at }}</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
      {% endfor %}
```

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: You will need to share your `urls.py` file too but generally in your views you need to filter which sections you want and attach them in the `render` call like you are doing in the `home` function.  
I suggest you go over the django official tutorials at least up to [tutorial 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/) but ideally the whole thing

Comment: i tried let me explain you with a example let assume that in subject model i created some table for math, chemistry, biology etcetra and i after that i created table in section like triangle related to math, acid related to chemistry, cell related to biology, and what i want i when i click on math it only show me the triangle which is related section not all them i guess you understand my issue in short acc to the subject sections will open which is related

Comment: And when i do like the home function it show all section no matter which subject is related

Comment: you need to have the section id as a parameter in the url for the section view, go through the tutorials that I mentioned, they go through this whole thing

Comment: will you please write the code which you are talking because i tried all acc to me and yeah i read tha thank you

Comment: @Jimmar any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `models.py`, change your `subject` in `Section` class to include the `related_name` attribute

```py
class Section(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name="section" on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # .... the rest of your fields
```

Then edit your `sections` in views to be

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def sections(request, subject_id):
    subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, pk=subject_id) # retrieve the subject 
    section_list = subject.section.all() # get the sections related to the subject
    print(section_list) 
    return render (request, 'sections.html',{"section_list" : section_list})
```

and in your `urls.py` add this as one of the `urlpatterns`

```py
path('section/<int:subject_id>/', views.sections, name='section'),
```

as for your `home.html`

```py
<ul>
    {% for subject in subject_list %}
    <li> 
      <a href="{% url 'section' subject.id %}">
        <img class="thumbnail"  src="{{ subject.thumbnail.url }}" alt=""> 
          <span><strong> {{ subject.name }} </strong> </span> 
      </a>
          <p>No of Section : {{ subject.total_section }} </p> 
    </li>
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and your `sections.html`

```py
<ul>
    {% for section in section_list %}
        <li> {{ section.title }} </li>
    {$ endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: it showing error Reverse for 'section' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['section/(?P<section_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: three one in my project second one in my accounts app and third one in my subjects app but why it matter please

Comment: my bad, it should have been subject.id in the home.html, I edited it

Comment: after clicking on asubject ink showing error

Comment: AttributeError at /section/3/
'Subject' object has no attribute 'section_set'

Comment: @Shreyash check again now, I added a modification to the `models.py` (you probably already did that which is what caused the error) and changed view (you can click on the "edited time ago" link under the question to see what changed)

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: yesit load the page now but no section is showing on the page i also look by inspecting it and <ul> is empty

Comment: @Shreyash Edit sections variable to be section_list (like I did) , but are you sure that the subject you have does have sections under it? I also added a print statement see if they do get printed to console

Answer (score 1):

*Answer fully edited to take into account the modifications you made in your requirements.*

**1. The model:**

Please add a related name to the foreign key to improve readability:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sections')
```

**2. The subject page :**

Where you can show all the sections related to the selected subject.

**The view:**

You take a second argument to know which subject you should display:

```
@login_required
def sections(request, subject_id):

    try: # First, you get the requested subject (if it exists)
        subject = Subject.objects.get(id=subject_id)
    except Subject.DoesNotExist: # Use Django shortcuts to display 404 if necessary
        raise Http404("There is no subject with this id.")

    sections = subject.sections

    return render (request, 'sections.html', {'sections': sections})
```

**The template:**

You can know access the sections fields by using `{{section.field}}` in a forloop:

```
<ul>
    {% for section in sections %}
    <li class="sub"> 
        <a name='thumb' class="thumb" href="#">
            <span><strong> {{ section.title }} </strong> </span> 
        </a>
        <p>Name: {{ section.teacher }} </p> 
        {{ section.price }} 
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**3. The home page :**

**The view:**

The view can stay the same:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    subject_list = Subject.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'home.html', {'subject_list': subject_list })
```

**The template:**

You change the url tag by giving the correct url name and the id of the section to display:

```
<ul>
    {% for subject in subject_list %}
    <li class="sub"> 
        <a name='thumb' class="thumb" href="{% url 'section' subject.id %}">
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="{{ subject.thumbnail.url }}" alt=""> 
            <span><strong> {{ subject.name }} </strong> </span> 
        </a>
        <p>No of Section : {{ subject.total_section }} </p> 
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**4. The URLs:**

You have to add the new argument that we are using for the section:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.my_login, name='login'),
    path('section/<int:subject_id>/', views.sections, name='section'),
]
```

And this should work.

Comment: showing error Reverse for 'section' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['section/(?P<section_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: @Shreyash Check if subject.section is None, which would mean that you forgot to bind the section to the subject when you create it. If it is not, please post the generated URL.

Comment: added as you asked

Comment: @Shreyash I was maybe not clear enough but I was just talking about the generated URL. Go to the page with your browser, right click on the link and click on the "copy address link" button.

Comment: @Shreyash I edited my answer to add a 4th step. Can you follow it and share what is printed in your console?

Comment: showing AttributeError at /SectionWise/
'Subject' object has no attribute 'session'

Comment: @Shreyash Sorry, I made a typo in that 4th state, I obviously meant `print(subject.section)`.  I edited the answer.

Comment: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /SectionWise/
Subject has no section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234727/discussion-between-shreyash-and-mickael-martinez).

Comment: @Shreyash I edited my anwser to take into account the changes you made during our discussion in the chat.